# Dúvida sobre encontrar informação no banco de dados

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, sqlite, login

Estou tentando fazer um sistema simples de *login*, gostaria que o sistema verificasse os *logins* que já estão cadastrados no banco de dados, para que não tenha mais de um igual cadastrado. Estou usando o *SqLite3* como banco.

Eu estou fazendo assim.

```
import sqlite3

banco = sqlite3.connect('sistema_cadastro.db')
cursor = banco.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT login FROM usuarios")
banco.commit()
tabela = cursor.fetchall()
print(tabela)
login = [tabela]
str(login)
if 'bruno' in login:
    print('Encontrou! (: ')
else:
    print('Não encontrou ): ')
banco.close()
```

Estou fazendo um *select* de 'login' na tabela 'usuarios' e dando um print
O print está mostrando a seguinte informação:

```
[('adm',), ('bruno',), ('teste',)]
```

Logo em seguida, coloquei um `if` procurando 'bruno' na lista 'login'.
Mas ele não acha, e sempre joga para o `else`.
**Gostaria de ver uma forma de ele procurar a variável 'bruno' na lista 'login'.**

Comment: Faça isso em SQL,por exemplo(desconheço a sua estrutura de dados mas), `SELECT login FROM usuarios where nome="bruno"`

Answer (score -2):

O retorno de um banco de dados consiste em uma lista de tuplas, ou seja, você deve acessar a lista, logo após o conteúdo das tuplas e procurar pela informação necessária. Com apenas um "IF " o seu código estará utilizando apenas a primeira lista como parâmetro. Com isso, aconselho que você utilize um laço "FOR" para percorrer todo o conteúdo da lista (as tuplas) e por último um "IF IN" nas tuplas para que o programa possa acessar as strings e, ao encontrar a informação desejada, ele possa executar o código de caso verdadeiro. Ainda dou a dica de utilizar as funções Index(retorna o Index de um valor da coleção) e len(retorna o tamanho da coleção) para imprimir a negação apenas quando o programa finalizar a busca em toda a lista, além de um break no fim da execução do IF para sair do laço FOR quando o valor procurado for encontrado. Em anexo mando um exemplo para que você possa entender melhor a explicação:

```py
b = [('bruno',), ('rodrigo',), ('joana',)]

for x in b:
        if 'rodrigo' in x:
            print('Nome encontrado :)')
            break
        elif b.index(x) == len(b) -1:
            print('Nome não encontrado :(')
```